# Standard for batteries in emergency lights

Tags: batteries, standard

I am not sure if this question fits this community.

I would like to know if there is any norm or standard for batteries in emergency lights for rail purposes in European countries, for example, some ISO or BS EN standards.

Comment: Could be many standards: spark or explosion mitigation, duration ie how long the lights must be on after power goes out, perhaps check out exit lights and fire regulations.

Comment: It depends: which country? And, what cell chemistry?

Answer (score 2):

https://electrical.theiet.org/wiring-matters/years/2017/66-july-2017/a-brief-overview-of-emergency-lighting-in-rail/

I found this using the following keywords copied from your question.

***emergency lights for rail purposes***

This covers the more important reasons for requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I found some standards.  There is no one just related specifically to emergency lights in trains, but standards for each kind of battery that are used in trains do exist.

- IEC 62973 *Railway applications – Batteries for auxiliary power supply systems*
- IEC 62973-2 *Nickel Cadmium*
- IEC 62973-4 *Nickel Metal Hydride*
- IEC 62928 *Railway applications – Rolling stock – Onboard lithium-ion traction batteries*